# Spring boot @Autowired и библиотека Telegrambots

Tags: java, telegram-bot, spring-boot

Столкнулся с проблемой. У библиотеки Telegrambots для использования с Http proxy нужно использовать вот такой конструктор:

```
    public TelegramLongPollingBot(DefaultBotOptions options) {
       super(options);
    }
```

Нужно передать параметр DefaultBotOptions options. Но как это сделать через аннотацию я не могу понять.

Если сделать вот так:

```
@Autowired
public TelegramBot(DefaultBotOptions options){
    super(options);
}
```

то ругается, что
Could not autowire. No beans of 'DefaultBotOptions' type found. Checks autowiring problems in a bean class.

Понятно, что DefaultBotOptions не bean, потому что из библиотеки.

Как все таки использовать конструктор с параметрами и @Autowired?

P.S. Может не совсем понятно объяснил проблему.

Comment: не использовать autowired! его не рекомендуется в новой версии спринга использовать. внедряешь через конструктор

Comment: @Санаев опа, это что-то новенькое! А можно ссылку на документацию, где это не рекомендуется?

Comment: @Санаев,  Через конструктор для упрощения unit тестирования, а не в новой версии

Comment: @NickSavenia ну вот по этому причине не рекомендуется использовать autowired. в спринге в документации по моему об этом написано. можно использовать аннотацию ломбок AllArgsConstructor меньше кода будет

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev где то в документациях об этом было сказано. посмотрите

Comment: @Санаев я не вылажу из документации Spring'а, так давно и много с ним работаю, и не помню там такого.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev у ломбока есть аннотация AllArgsConstructor то есть, можно не писать конструктор, autowired ломбок все за вас сделает. думаю так правильней.

Answer (score 0):

Создайте руками:

```
@Bean
public TelegramLongPollingBot telegramLongPollingBot() {
    return new TelegramLongPollingBot(new DefaultBotOptions());
}
```